# LINQ to SQL-- Best learning resources?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

It's not that I can't google for myself, however others have tread this path before me and I"m always interested in what other programmers have found helpful, or not :)

Thanks in advance for any input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hands down IMHO, an excellent read...

http://linqinaction.net/

Comment: This book isn't all examples and short disconnected sentences right after another, its written to be read.

Answer (score 1):

asp.net is the first place I go.

Scott Gu's blog has a good Linq to SQL series as well.
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/07/linq-to-sql-part-9-using-a-custom-linq-expression-with-the-lt-asp-linqdatasource-gt-control.aspx

I'm sure someone will mention that you might want to take a look at Linq to Entities as Linq to SQL isn't going to be getting much attention from Microsoft in the future.

Comment: Don't worry about this. Linq to SQL is still really good. Linq to Entities (Entity Framework) really isn't good to use yet. Give it another year for Entity Framework. I use Linq to SQL for lots of stuff. It's great.

Answer (score 1):

If I was a betting man (and I am), I would start to learn the Entity Framework. While individuals on the surface have been noting that this is just another attempt by Microsoft to kill a popular application (linqToSQL) with a "new" one; it's not. The overall vision and direction that EF is heading is actually really impressive when you get into the nuts and/or bolts.

However, for me, personally, the light flickered on when I read Manning Press' "[Linq In Action](http://linqinaction.net/)". Not only is [Fabrice Marguerie](http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/about.aspx) a great resource for all things LINQ; he has an uncanny ability to make things pleasant to read and understand.